# does I need to change my project name

Tags: ios, xcode

I have upload my app to app store. And it ask me project name I gave "Tour of kenaya ".But actually my project name in xcode is "kenaya".

So my doubt is ?. When my app get ok and when its available in app store. And if user download my app means.My app name will be "Kenaya" or "Tour of kenaya ".

Please help me out.i am confused.This is my first app in ios.

Answer (score 1):

In your info.plist, set the `CFBundleDisplayName` and `CFBundleName`. More details here : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html

For your the app name visible in the store, you have to set it in itunes connect.

The name of your project has nothing to do with the app name.

Comment: yes, in my info.plist i set the bundle display name to "Tour of kenaya"..Then i am correct right ??..When user download my app  -  they can see the name `Tour of kenaya`..Right??

Comment: @user5513630 Yes, the name below the icon is the CFBundleDisplayName. It easy to check. In your device / simulator, what is displayed ?

Comment: @user5513630 The CFBundleName is used in the list of apps stored in iTunes library. So if your app ask authorization like photo library, push notification etc... I recommend you to set this key too.

Answer (score 0):

in `Info.plist` `set Bundle display` name equal (Tour of kenaya).
in your case the name in iTunes (App Store) will be (Tour of kenaya) and name display in iPhone or iPad will be (Kenaya).so you must edit it and resubmit to store.

Comment: this link will help you https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1892/_index.html